# How to extract and create a new column in a data set, based on an already existing column

Tags: python, r, regex

An example slice from 2 columns in my data set, needed for later.

```
**City**    **Ranking**
 Boston        9  of 2972
 Boston        60 of 2972
 Miami         6  of 1444
 Miami         200 of 1444
 Miami          3  of 1444
 Miami          1  of 1444
```

I want to create a new column called `individual.rank`. it's based on the `Ranking` column.  I know how to print data rows related to each city, I just need to know how to extract and how to do the `individual.rank` column.
the result should be like that for table of Miami for example:

```
**City**   **Ranking**  **individual.rank**
 Miami       1 of 1444          1
 Miami       2 of 1444          2
 Miami       3 of 1444          3
```

sorting the `Ranking` I can do like that for a specific city:

```
MiamiTable = data.loc[data['City'] == 'Miami']
MiamiTable.sort_values('Ranking')
```

I have this in R using functions I don't understand, and regex. but I don't know how to do it in Python. (`df.restaurant.data` is the data set) :

```
pattern <- "[0-9?,]+" # 
pattern.end <- "[0-9?,]+$"
df.restaurant.data <- df.restaurant.data %>%  
    mutate(individual.rank = str_replace(str_extract(Ranking, pattern),
                                         ",", "") %>% 
               as.numeric())
```

Comment: You need someone who understands both the `dplyr`-variant of R and Python. Code appears to just be using regex to extract numbers with commas. Why the "?" is inside a character class is bit of a puzzle though. And why passing digit strings with commas to `as.numeric` should work in R is also a bit of a puzzle. I'm skeptical that this is solidly tested R code. My advice: Edit your question to capitalize all the "I"'s, since many of us fiund that to be sign of laziness and lack of respect for your readers,  and remove the request to translate from sketchy R code.

Comment: normally a question requies some code that one can I paste and run to replicate your progress in your task, or your error, otherwise it is a 'do my work' call, something not widely appreciated at Stackoverflow

Comment: I just need to understand how to create a table for a city like Miami or any other cities, with my desired new column and ranking arranged as the new table posted above. You can ignore the R code slice and try to focus on how to implement it in Python, because that's my difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `pandas`? If so, this seems to achieve what you're after.

```
MiamiTable = data.loc[data['City'] == 'Miami']

MiamiTable['individual_rank'] = MiamiTable.Ranking.str.replace(r' .*', '').astype('int')
```

Doing a string replace to remove anything after (and including) the first space, then converting the result to integer. Then sort:

```
MiamiTable.sort_values('individual_rank')


    City      Ranking  individual_rank
5  Miami   1  of 1444                1
4  Miami   3  of 1444                3
2  Miami   6  of 1444                6
3  Miami  200 of 1444              200
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use two R packages: tidyr and dplyr:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(City = c("Boston", "Boston", rep("Miami", 4)),
             Ranking = c("9  of 2972",
                         "60 of 2972",
                         "6  of 1444",
                         "200 of 1444",
                         "3  of 1444",
                         "1  of 1444"))

df %>% 
  separate(col = Ranking, into = c("individual.rank", "total"), 
           sep = "of", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars("individual.rank"), as.integer) %>% 
  select(-total)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  City   Ranking     individual.rank
  <chr>  <chr>                 <int>
1 Boston 9  of 2972                9
2 Boston 60 of 2972               60
3 Miami  6  of 1444                6
4 Miami  200 of 1444             200
5 Miami  3  of 1444                3
6 Miami  1  of 1444                1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression where it is something like `df$new_col <- gsub(".*of","", df$original_col)`